# Django: 'module' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I've been trying to learn Django for the past few days, but recently I've stumbled upon a problem I can't seem to fix. After finishing Django's own tutorial on writing your first app I decided to go through it again. Only now I would replace everything to fit the requirements of the original app I was building.

So, everything went well until I got to part 3. When I try to load `http://localhost:8000/lru/` I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError at /lru/
'module' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 69, in process_request
    if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 551, in is_valid_path
    resolve(path, urlconf)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 440, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/oyvindhellenes/Desktop/Sommerjobb 2013/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    url(r'^lru/', include('lru.urls', namespace="lru")),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 25, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/oyvindhellenes/Desktop/Sommerjobb 2013/mysite/lru/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'index'
```

My code:

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")
```

lru/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from lru import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^lru/', include('lru.urls', namespace="lru")),
)
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
mysite/
    lru
    templates
    polls
    manage.py
    mysite

lru/
    templates
    urls.py
    admin.py
    __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

It's strange because I've done everything exactly as I did in the "polls" example turtorial. Just replacing the names. When I comment out `url(r'^lru/', include('lru.urls', namespace="lru")),` in mysite/urls.py, then `http://localhost:8000/polls/` works fine, but I just can't seem to get /lru to work.

This is really killing me so any form of help would be appreciative!

**Edit: Added full traceback**

Comment: Which file and line does the error occur in?

Comment: Could you show the full traceback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either do this :

```
from lru.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', index, name='index')
)
```

or

```
from lru import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', 'views.index', name='index')
)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you! 

But I don't get why /polls works without importing...

Comment: I think it's a good idea to wait for one day before marking an answer as correct, since answers are sometimes suboptimal even if they seem to solve the problem. In this particular answer, I don't like the `import *` in the first solution (it's bad practice), and I don't understand why the `from lru import views` statement is needed in the second solution.

Comment: Your probably right. Im new here so don't know the norms yet.

As for the import statement (`from lru import views`). I get `NameError at /lru/
name 'views' is not defined`
if I remove it so I guess its needed.

Comment: yes i do agree sir, its also about the best practice , but that's where you by yourself need to think whether it should be `from lru.views import *` or it should be `from lru.views import view1, view2` . It depends on the current situation , but obviously if you are making views than they always map to some url i think if i am correct and in second case `from lru import views` .. it was his requirement ... and he asked to solve the issue ..

Comment: -1. This is a bad answer. You don't need *both* to import the views file *and* to use a string: either one makes the other irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

Import the urls.py module into your view. like this;

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import urls

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `url()` should be string, anway I would change the `lru/urls.py` to:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'lru.views.index', name='lru-index')
)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that Sublime text was mixing .... and tabs to make indentation, depending, I guess, on the copy/paste source.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Django URLs works:

1. The urls from `mysite/mysite/urls` includes `mysite/polls/urls`, which tells that there are polls created inside the mysite project;
2. The `mysite/polls/urls` file tells us that the url "polls/", whenever visited, should call the function `index()` from `mysite/polls/views` which is what it states when you type the line:

```
    urlpatterns = [    
        path('', views.index, name = 'index'),    
    ]
```

3. And a very important thing to remember is to save **each edited file** before you run the server, so that files get updated. You can also keep the server running and save the files.