# Adding a Second URL Pattern in Django Causes Attribute Error

Tags: python, django

This is related to [Django: 'module' object has no attribute 'index'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880146/django-module-object-has-no-attribute-index).

I have very similar files to that poster, and have been following the same first django tutorial. Here's my project/urls.py. A slight modification causes it to fail.

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    #url(r'^redis/', include('redis.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Uncommenting that line causes this error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Edit: I have implemented the other question's solution, but I would like to know why this breaks it. Shouldn't it just return the wrong module's index, rather than an AttributeError?

Comment: The error is probably in your polls/urls.py file... which you haven't shown but the solution is the same as the duplicate.

Comment: Or, your `redis/urls.py` file